# django froala upload images

Tags: django, upload, editor

My django-froala-editor works all fine except for uploading images
The images upload fine. but the images don't show in the editor

my template to get the editor:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Create Article</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {# load editor shizzle #}    


        <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ form.title.label }}</label>
            {{ form.title|addcss:"form-control" }} <span class="form-errors">{{ form.title.errors.as_text}}</span>
        </div>
        {{ form.media }}
        {{ form.body }}

        {{ form.published.label }} {{ form.published }}
        {{ form.public.label }} {{ form.public }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Save</button>
    </form>
```

any idea what the problem could be?

My dev_server spews: /data/media/uploads/froala_editor/images/avatar_XqIhnSI.png HTTP/1.1" 404 6421

However that is the exact location to the image. . .

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're not returning the right URL to the image. Your response should be a JSON like this: {link: "link_to_the_uploaded_image}. You should check in JS console to see what the upload request returns.